# ActivityIndicator doesn't stop inside collectionviewcell

Tags: uicollectionview, uiactivityindicatorview

I'm using a UICollectionView inside a UITableViewCell to show images inside a tableviewcell.
While downloading the photo in background the activity indicator should be animated en no image shown. Once the photo is downloaded the activity indicator should stop animating and the photo should be shown.
Everything works except for the first time the first cell is shown. The image is shown and the activity indicator keeps on animating. If I scroll the collectionView, it works for the other images and when I scroll back to the first image, it also works. It's only on the first time the first image is shown

The cell inside the collectionview is call PhotoCollectionView and the header looks like:

```
@interface PhotoCollectionCell : UICollectionViewCell

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator;

@end
```

Code for cellForItemAtIndexPath

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"PhotoCollectionCell";
    PhotoCollectionCell *cell = (PhotoCollectionCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.imageView.image = nil;

    UIImage *image = [thumbnails objectForKey:indexPath];
    if(!image) {
        [cell.activityIndicator startAnimating];
        if (self.pictureCollectionView.dragging == NO && self.pictureCollectionView.decelerating == NO)
        {
            [self startDownload:images[indexPath.row] forIndexPath:indexPath];
        }
    } else {
        [cell.activityIndicator stopAnimating];
        cell.imageView.image = image;
    }

    return cell;
}
```

I tried several solutions given on the web, everything is executing on the main thread, so i don't know what to do anymore.

Help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance. Kind regards...